# Formatação de strings no console usando js

Tags: javascript

Em um bootcamp foi dado o seguinte desafio:

O seu instrutor de lógica de programação, Damilson Bonetti, quer que você desenvolva uma tela com as seguintes características:

Conter 39 traços horizontais ( - ) na primeira linha;
Conter um traço vertical ( | ) embaixo do primeiro traço e do trigésimo nono traço da primeira linha, preencher no meio com espaço em branco;
Repita o procedimento 2 quatro vezes;
Repita o procedimento 1.

--------------------------------------- (39 traços)

|                                     |

|                                     |

|                                     |

|                                     |

|                                     |

--------------------------------------- (39 traços)

Que método ou função do Javascript eu posso usar para chegar a esse resultado de saída?

Answer (score -2):

Se você deseja exibir o resultado no console do navegador, vai precisar utilizar uma estrutura de repetição "FOR" para gerar cada linha, e dentro de cada linha usar um segundo "FOR" para definir a estrutura da linha. Além disso, você vai precisar usar "IFs" para determinar qual o caracter inicial ou final da linha.

De acordo com as condições que você informou, o código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
    var resultado = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 39; j++) {
            if (i == 1 || i == 7)
                resultado += "-";
            else if (j == 1 || j == 39)
                resultado += "|";
            else 
                resultado += " ";
        }
        resultado += "\n";
    }
    console.log(resultado);
```